# How to only re-render individual child components with useRef and useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, use-ref

tl;dr - how to force re-render only one specific child component by tracking `ref`?

I have a table of rows. I'd like to be able to hover on rows and show/hide a cell in the row, but only after a while.

You can only reveal hidden hover content after hovering over the entire table for some period of time - triggered by `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave`.

Once hovering a particular `<Row>`, it should show the extra content if it's allowed to by the parent.

The sequence for mouse over the table:

1. Hover over row
2. Row's `isHovered` is now `true`
3. In 1000ms, `allowHover` changes to `true`
4. Since `allowHover` and `isHovered` are both `true`, show extra row content

The sequence for mouse OUT the table:

1. Mouse moves outside of the parent container/table/row
2. Previously hovered row's `isHovered` is set to `false`
3. Previously hovered row's hidden content is hidden
4. In 1000ms, `allowHover` changes to `false`

At this point, if re-entering the table, we'd have to wait for 1 second again before `allowHover` is true. Once both `isHovered` and `allowHover` are true, display hidden content. Once hover is allowed, there are no delays involved: rows hovered over should immediately reveal the hidden content.

**I'm trying to employ `useRef` to avoid mutating state of the rows' parent and causing a re-render of all the child rows**

At the row level, on hover, a row should be able to check if hover is allowed without the entire list being re-rendered with props. I assumed `useEffect` could be set to track the value but it doesn't seem to trigger a re-render at the individual component level.

In other words, **expected behavior is for the currently hovered over row to detect the change in the parent and only re-render itself to reveal content**. Then, once hovering is allowed the behavior is straightforward. Hover over row? Reveal its content.

Here's the snippets of code involved:

```
function Table() {
  const allowHover = useRef(false);

  const onMouseEnter = (e) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      allowHover.current = true; // allow hovering
    }, 1000);
  };
  const onMouseLeave = (e) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      allowHover.current = false; // dont allow hovering
    }, 1000);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App" style={{ border: '3px solid blue' }}>
      <h1>table</h1>
      {/* allow/disallow hovering when entering and exiting the table, with a delay */}
      <table onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={onMouseLeave}>
        <tbody>
          <AllRows allowHover={allowHover} />
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

function Rows(props) {
  return [1, 2, 3].map((id) => (
    <Row id={id} allowHover={props.allowHover} />
  ));
}

function Row(props) {
  let [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Why isn't this re-rendering this component?
  }, [props.allowHover]);

  const onMouseEnter = ({ target }) => {
    setIsHovered(true);
  };
  const onMouseLeave = ({ target }) => {
    setIsHovered(false);
  };

  console.log('RENDERING ROW');
  return (
    <tr key={props.id} onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={onMouseLeave}>
      <td style={{ border: '1px solid red' }}>---------------- {props.id}</td>
      <td style={{ border: '1px solid green' }}>
        {props.allowHover.current && isHovered ? (
          <button>ACTIONS</button>
        ) : null}
      </td>
    </tr>
  );
}
```

Comment: Is the goal to avoid rendering the whole table when a single row needs to update? If so, have you considered using [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo)?

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah If I set "allowHover" as a prop, then every time the cursor enters/exits the table, that prop will change for every child element. That's what I'm trying to avoid - am I missing something? Hover over row = do something to only that row. Hover over whole table = re-render all rows because the table's state is now changed.

Comment: I'm not 100% understanding your use case, but I'll say that if you're looking to avoid re-rendering, then consider using React.memo to prevent a re-render based on current and next props. You may need to re-structure some components such that you're able to prevent as much of the table from re-rendering as possible (or until performance is good).

Lastly, if you don't have any performance issues now, then I'd avoid these optimizations.

Comment: I'm aware of memo, but it's not useful here as this parent state change needs to propagate down to all children. If I could avoid notifying all children of the change, memo would be great, but that's not the case here. Imagine if I had `window.allowHover` - is there a way to make an individual row react to that? I'm passing the equivalent of that through props but `useEffect` doesn't do anything when the value changes. How can I re-render just that element without changing parent state (and thus rerendering everything, every time)?

Comment: With React.memo, you can let the parent state change and prevent each row from re-rendering

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah but that's only if the child rows receive the SAME props though. Right? In this case, they would all get separate props.

Comment: This is a VERY particular use-case! :) I take it that whenever we enter the table, we have to wait 1 s, then the currently hovered row is immediately shown as long as we stay in the table. When we get out of the table for more than 1 sec, we have to redo the 1s quarantine before rows are shown again. You state at the top CELLS and then ROWS, which is it? Also, you're mixing two different strategies here... you say that you want to use refs and update the DOM outside of React but at the same time, you want to use React to keep track of what is updated and what is not ... That's contradictory!

Comment: All in all, don't update the DOM via refs if you don't need to. Always start by using React as intended and then, if you're not happy, start thinking about how you can improve the existing code and THEN, as a last resort, use refs and bypass React. In your usecase, I see no reason for not using React throughout, these operations are not going to be too heavy for React to update the DOM smoothly and so you should simplify the code and use React. I can provide an example once you confirm that I have understood things correctly.

Comment: Also, now you're ADDING and REMOVING the button depending on if it should be shown, you could also set its `display` to `none` or its `visibility` to `hidden`, are these options as well?

Comment: @mcderp you can pass a function to React.memo to decide if that component should re-render. Check the docs!

Comment: @fast-reflexes your assessment sounds good. mousein table -> 1 sec -> show currently hovered row. Hover over to a different row - no delay. Hover out of the table for 0.2s and return? All good. Hover outside the table for longer than 1s? Start over with the delay. CSS visibility tools are an option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Basics

### React

One, if not **THE**, biggest of React's advantages is that it lets us manage an application with state without interacting with the DOM via manual updates and event listeners. Whenever React "rerenders", it renders a virtual DOM which it then compares to the actual DOM, doing replacements where necessary.

### Hooks

- `useState`: returns a state and a setter, whenever the setter is executed with a new state, the component rerenders.
- `useRef`: provides a possibility to keep a reference to a value or object between renders. It's like a wrapper around a variable which is stored at the ref's `current` property and which is referentially identical between renders as long as you don't change it. Setting a new value to a ref does **NOT** cause the component to rerender. You can attach actual DOM nodes to refs but you can really attach anything to a ref.
- `useEffect`: code to run after a component has rendered. The `useEffect` is executed after the DOM has been updated.
- `memo`: adds possibility to manually control when a child rerenders after the parent has rerendered.

## Your code

I'm going to assume that this is some kind of toy example and that you want to understand how React works, if not, doing this by direct manipulation of DOM nodes is not the way to go. As a matter of fact, you should ***ONLY*** use `memo` and performances improvements and direct manipulation of DOM nodes when it's not possible to accomplish what you want in another way, or if doing it the the regular way with React does not yield acceptable performance. In your case, the performance would be good enough.

There are libraries that do most of the work outside of React. One of those is `react-spring` which animates DOM elements. Doing these animations in React would slow them down and make them lag, therefore `react-spring` uses refs and updates DOM nodes directly, setting different CSS properties right on the element.

## Your questions

- You wonder why the `useEffect` in `Row` is not triggered whenever you change the content of the ref. Well, this is simply because `useEffect` runs after render, and there is no guarantee that the component will rerender just because you change the content of the `allowHover` ref. The ref passed to `AllRows` and `Row` is the same property all the time (only its `current` property changes), therefore they will never rerender due to props being changed. Since `Row` only rerenders, by itself, when `isHovered` is set, there is no guarantee that the `useEffect` will fire just because you change the content of `allowHover` ref. ***WHEN*** `Row` rerenders, the effect will run ***IF*** the value of `allowHover.current` is different from last time.
- Using `memo` will not help you here either since `Table` or `AllRows` don't rerender either. `memo` allows us to skip rerendering children when parents rerender, but here, the parents don't rerender, so `memo` will do nothing.

All in all, neither `useEffect` or `memo` are some kind of magic functions that keep track of variables at all times and then do something when these change, instead, they are just functions that are executed at given times in the React lifecycle, evaluating the current context.

## Your use case

Basically, whether a `Row` should be visible or not depends on two conditions:

- Is `allowHover.current` set to `true`?
- Is `isHovered` set to `true`?

Since these don't depend on each other, we should ideally like to be able to modify the conditional content from event listeners attached to both of the events which change the values of these properties.

In a vanilla Javascript environment, we would perhaps store each element depending on this in an array and set its `display` or `visibility` from the event listeners which would check both of these conditions; whichever event listener that fires last would be responsible for showing or hiding the component / row.

Doing the same in React, but bypassing React, should be quite straightforward as long as you can store this state in some ref. Since both events occurring on `Table` level and `Row` level have to be able to modify the elements in question, access to these DOM elements must be available in both of these components. You can accomplish this by either merging the code of `Table`, `Row` and `AllRows` into one component or pass refs from the children back up to the parent component in some elaborate scheme. The point here is, if you want to do it outside of React, ***ALL*** of this should be done outside of React.

Your current problem in the code is that you want to update one of the conditions (`allowHover`) outside of React but you want React to take care of the other condition (`isHovered`). This creates an odd situation which is not advisable no matter if you would really want to do this outside of React (which I advise against in all cases except toy scenarios) or not. React does not know when `allowHover` is set to `true` since this is done outside of React.

## Solutions

### 1. Use React

Simply use `useState` for the `allowHover` so that `Table` rerenders whenever `allowHover` changes. This will update the prop in the children which will rerender too. Also make sure to store the timeout in a ref so that you may clear it whenever you move the mouse in and out of the table.

With this solution, the `Table` and all its children will rerender whenever the mouse passes in and out of the table (after 1 s.) and then individual `Row`s will rerender whenever `isHovered` for that `Row` is changed. The result is that `Row`s will rerender on both the conditions which control whether they should contain the conditional content or not.

```
function Table() {

  const [allowHover, setAllowHover] = useState(false);
  const [currentRow, setCurrentRow] = useState(null);
  const hoverTimeout = useRef(null);

  const onHover = (id) => setCurrentRow(id);

  const onMouseEnter = (e) => {
    if (hoverTimeout.current !== null) clearTimeout(hoverTimeout.current);
    hoverTimeout.current = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Enabling hover");
      setAllowHover(true); // allow hovering
    }, 1000);
  };

  const onMouseLeave = (e) => {
    if (hoverTimeout.current !== null) clearTimeout(hoverTimeout.current);
    hoverTimeout.current = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Disabling hover");
      setAllowHover(false); // dont allow hovering
      setCurrentRow(null);
    }, 1000);
  };

  console.log("Rendering table");

  return (
    <div className="App" style={{ border: "3px solid blue" }}>
      <h1>table</h1>
      {/* allow/disallow hovering when entering and exiting the table, with a delay */}
      <table
        style={{ border: "3px solid red" }}
        onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter}
        onMouseLeave={onMouseLeave}
      >
        <tbody>
          <Rows onHover={onHover} currentRow={allowHover ? currentRow : null} />
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

function Rows(props) {

  console.log("Rendering rows");

  return [1, 2, 3].map((id) => (
    <Row
      id={id}
      key={id}
      isActive={props.currentRow === id}
      onHover={() => props.onHover(id)}
    />
  ));
}

function Row(props) {

  console.log("Rendering row");

  return (
    <tr key={props.id} onMouseEnter={props.onHover}>
      <td style={{ border: "1px solid red" }}>---------------- {props.id}</td>
      <td style={{ border: "1px solid green" }}>
        {props.isActive ? <button>ACTIONS</button> : null}
      </td>
    </tr>
  );
}
```

No funny business going on here, just plain React style.

Code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/bypass-react-1a-i3dq8

### 2. Bypass React

Even though not recommended, if you do this, you should do all the updates outside of React. This means you can't depend on React to rerender child rows when you update the state of the `Table` outside of React. You could do this in many ways, but one way is for child `Row`s to pass their refs back up to the `Table` component which manually updates the `Row`s via refs. This is pretty much what React does under the hood actually.

Here, we add a lot of logic to the `Table` component which becomes more complicated but instead, the `Row` components lose some code:

```
function Table() {

  const allowHover = useRef(false);
  const timeout = useRef(null);
  const rows = useRef({});
  const currentRow = useRef(null);

  const onAddRow = (row, id) => {
    rows.current = {
      ...rows.current,
      [id]: row
    };
    onUpdate();
  };

  const onHoverRow = (id) => {
    currentRow.current = id.toString();
    onUpdate();
  };

  const onUpdate = () => {
    Object.keys(rows.current).forEach((key) => {
      if (key === currentRow.current && allowHover.current) {
        rows.current[key].innerHTML = "<button>Accept</button>";
      } else {
        rows.current[key].innerHTML = "";
      }
    });
  };

  const onMouseEnter = (e) => {
    if (timeout.current !== null) clearTimeout(timeout.current);
    timeout.current = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Enabling hover on table");
      allowHover.current = true; // allow hovering
      onUpdate();
    }, 1000);
  };

  const onMouseLeave = (e) => {
    if (timeout.current !== null) clearTimeout(timeout.current);
    timeout.current = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Disabling hover on table");
      allowHover.current = false; // dont allow hovering
      currentRow.current = null;
      onUpdate();
    }, 1000);
  };

  console.log("Rendering table");

  return (
    <div className="App" style={{ border: "3px solid blue" }}>
      <h1>table</h1>
      {/* allow/disallow hovering when entering and exiting the table, with a delay */}
      <table onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={onMouseLeave}>
        <tbody>
          <Rows onAddRow={onAddRow} onHoverRow={onHoverRow} />
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

function Rows(props) {

  console.log("Rendering rows");

  return [1, 2, 3].map((id) => (
    <Row
      key={id}
      id={id}
      onAddRow={props.onAddRow}
      onHoverRow={() => props.onHoverRow(id)}
    />
  ));
}

function Row(props) {

  console.log("Rendering row");

  return (
    <tr onMouseEnter={props.onHoverRow} key={props.id}>
      <td style={{ border: "1px solid red" }}>---------------- {props.id}</td>
      <td
        ref={(ref) => props.onAddRow(ref, props.id)}
        style={{ border: "1px solid green" }}
      ></td>
    </tr>
  );
}
```

Code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/bypass-react-1b-rsqtq

You can see for yourself in the console that each component only renders once.

## Conclusion

Always first implement things inside React the usual way, then use `memo`, `useCallback`, `useMemo` and refs to improve performance where absolutely necessary. Remember that more complicated code also comes at a cost so just because you're saving some rerenderings with React doesn't mean you have arrived at a better solution.

## Update

I changed the code so that once a row has been hovered, it is registered as the current hovered row. This row will then not stop being hovered until another row is hovered or until the table has been disabled (1 s after mouse leaves table). A tiny problem here is that we may enter the table but **NOT** hover a row so that we are inside the table without any active row. This also means that if we leave the table in this state, no row will be "active" since none was active to begin with. This is due to that there is extra room in the table that is not allocated to any row. It works well despite this but it's good to be aware of. Alas, `table`s are not really layout components and the more particular your layout gets, the more this shows. If this is a problem, I would use flex-box instead or a `table` without cell spacing and borders. If borders are required, they could be added inside each cell with absolute positioning instead of relying on the table's spacing and borders.

Comment: Thanks for the amazing answer. the code sandbox is missing one crucial thing though - once the table is exited, the last selected value should persist for some time instead of disappearing right away. a setTimeout would work here I guess?

Comment: Aha I missed that part of the specification... So the element skulle remain for that 1 second or what?

Comment: Yes indeed. I think I could figure it out my own but I'd still like your input here. I did a poor job of explaining it but yes, once you enter the table there's 1s delay before you see anything and then as you exit the table, a highlighted row is visible for 1s. Think of how the UI would look for actions like view/edit/delete that you'd want to show up on hover but only after a while and then stay for a second as you're leaving the table. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Is you desire that once we have entered the table and 1 second has passed, SOME option will always be visible until we exit the table and 1 second has passed? Otherwise there is an ambiguity, because if we leave all rows but NOT leave the table, all rows will lose focus and not show the conditional content. If we now after this exit the table, it seems odd to make the last selected row selected again.

Comment: Another way to think about it: an item takes 1 second to appear only the first time the table is entered, 0s to appear when already inside of table and 1s to "fade out" when you leave the table. If you enter the table for 0.5s and leave - nothing hovers. If you enter for 1.1 seconds and leave - the item you hovered on stays for 1 second and hides. If you leave, then *re-enter* within 0.5 second, the item remains shown/hovered. Moving row to row has no delay. If you leave the table for 1.1, last hovered element stays on for 1 second then disappears.

Comment: I understand but there is ambiguity if you can be inside the table without being on a row. Therefore, as soon as you are in the table, you must touch a row and show the content of that row; there can be no space between rows nor padding nor border on the table because then it is not specified what should happen once this area is hovered.

Comment: >inside the table without being on a row
That counts as being inside the table. You can be in a table with huge padding, wait 1s and then rows become hoverable.

Comment: Sure, that's fine as long as you accept that no row is active as long as the actual ROW is not hovered

Comment: In the codebox yo usent, if you leave the table the final element just disappears instantly instead of staying hovered for a second. Other than that everything is perfect.

Comment: I have updated them :)

Comment: Heroic effort, thank you very much